# React hook form "onChange" mode is not working with custom input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, react-typescript

Here I have custom input component:

```
const FloatInput: FC<{
    label: string
    type?: React.HTMLInputTypeAttribute | undefined
    onChange?: () => void
    value?: string
    required?: boolean
    register?: any
}> = ({
    label,
    type = 'text',
    onChange,
    value,
    required = false,
    register
}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.wrapper}>
                <input
                    {...register}
                    required={required}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    className={styles.input}
                    type={type}
                    placeholder=' '
                />
                <label className={styles.label}>{label}</label>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

I use react-hook-form to handle it:

```
const Login = () => {
    const {
        handleSubmit,
        register,
        formState: { errors },
        reset
    } = useForm<ILoginInput>({
        mode: 'onChange'
    })
    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<ILoginInput> = data => {
        reset()
    }
    return (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <form
                onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                className={styles.form}
                method='post'>
                <div>
                    <FloatInput
                        register={register('email', {
                            required: 'Email is required',
                        })}
                        type='text'
                        label='Email'
                    />
                    {errors?.email && <p>{errors.email.message}</p>}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have no idea why `onChange` mode is not working, because when I try to submit form error shows up.
I was trying to put error block inside custom input component, but it also not worked.
Should I leave just default input in form or I can somehow fix that issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue.
That was not working because of `onChange={onChange}` in custom component. As I understand react-hook-form provide own onChange metod, but it was over written after destructuring `register` object in the custom component.